# Removal of warnings when I compile

Tags: c, function, pointers

This is a sample piece of code I am posting below. I am getting a warning when I compile this program as shown below:

```
    samp2.c: In function `main':
    samp2.c:37: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_func' from incompatible pointer type
```

The code is shown below:

```
     typedef enum TES_status_e
     {
          TES_stat_unknown,
          TES_stat_ok,
          TES_stat_too_high,
          TES_stat_too_low,
          TES_stat_short_GND,
          TES_stat_connected,
          TES_stat_not_connected

      } TES_status_t;

      typedef enum DIAG_status_e 
      {
          DIAG_stat_unknown,
          DIAG_stat_ok,
          DIAG_stat_too_high = 10,
          DIAG_stat_too_low,
          DIAG_stat_short_GND,
          DIAG_stat_connected,
          DIAG_stat_not_connected

      } DIAG_status_t;

     typedef int (*MyPtr)(TES_status_t);

     int my_func(MyPtr);

     int test(DIAG_status_t);

     main()
     {

           my_func(&test);  

     }


     int my_func(MyPtr Val)
     {
       Val(DIAG_stat_too_high);

     }
     int test(DIAG_status_t c)
     {
        printf("The val of c is %d\n",c);   
     }
```

This is the warning shown as below

```
          samp2.c: In function `main':
          samp2.c:37: warning: passing arg 1 of `my_func' from incompatible pointer type
```

Please let me know how to remove this warning.

Comment: Which Compiler ? GCC, Visual Studio ?

Comment: @aleroot ...gcc compiler

Comment: Why `MyPtr` is for `TES_status_t` and `test` is for `DIAG_status_t`?

Comment: Perhaps just try to understand what it says? an incompatible pointer type? Could this perhaps just be that you are passing in a pointer that has a type that is different from the type that the function expects?

Answer (score 2):

You declared my_func to take a function that accepts a TES_status_t enum as argument however the actual test function takes a DIAG_status_t argument that is why you get a warning.

Also the function takes a function pointer, but a function name like `test` is in fact a function pointer so you only need to supply the function name, not the address:

```
my_func((MyPtr)test);
```

Comment: @Anders...Thanks a lot.The warning got removed.Just wondering how was the analysis done?

Comment: @Maddy: this is a hack at best. If two weeks later you e.g. reorder the members in one of the `enum` definitions, your program will break for no obvious reason at all...

Answer (score 1):

Wait, the warning looks like it's right to me.

Despite what you may think, TES_status_t is not equivalent to DIAG_status_t.

I recommend that you fix your code, not the warning.

Answer (score 1):

GCC is right.

You define `MyPtr` as a pointer to a function that takes a `TES_status_t` argument and then supply a pointer to a function that takes a `DIAG_status_t` argument.

EDIT:

You can suppress the warning by explicitly casting to `MyPtr`: `my_func((MyPtr)test);`

*However* this is usually a recipe for disaster, because you essentially introduce non-obvious dependencies between types and the code that uses them.

True, enumerations in C are represented by an `int` type and in this case both enumerations seem to have a correspondence to each other. But what happens in two weeks when you decide to e.g. add a new state in `DIAG_status_t`? Your program will break subtly and you will have a hard time tracking the problem because you will have ignored what little type checking the compiler does for you.

Comment: @Thkala...Thanks for those inputs.Now i am just checking how to break this programe.I mean is there anyway by which i can crash this programe

Answer (score 0):

my_func expects a pointer to a function taking TES_status_t value and returning an int.

You're calling it with a pointer to a function taking a DIAG_status_t and returning an int.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the line 37 of your `samp2.c` file till you get no more warnings. Don't turn compiler warnings off, they are very useful. If using `gcc`, ask for (almost) all of them with `-Wall`.

A `TES_status_t` value is not a `DIAG_status_t` value (but don't think that casting `TES_stat_too_high` to a `DIAG_status_t` will give you `DIAG_stat_too_high`)

Comment: @Basile..Yes.Is there anyway to fix the warning.I mean i cant change the argument of my_func as this argument should go for my_func